# Is there an image map plugin for the CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I found one for the FCK editor but I need one for the CKEditor

http://martinezdelizarrondo.com/imagemaps/

Comment: It *might* be possible to port that plug-in with relatively little work if you're somewhat experienced in JavaScript... Make sure to also check on CKEditor's support site.

Comment: The sad part is that the paypal button stating that it can be used to improve the plugin hasn't ever been used. So if no one has used previously the plugin in FCKeditor and thought that it's worth to send a few bucks, why should I develop a new version or make it available as open source?

Answer (score 0):

By now there is also a version for CKeditor (4): http://www.martinezdelizarrondo.com/ckplugins/imagemaps.demo4/